# SQL error when using DQL with symfony

Tags: sql, symfony, dql

I am using symfony framework, and when I tried this DQL methode to recover username for the Fos_user table generated by the FOSUser bundle

```
namespace UserBundle\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findEmailDQL($email)
    {
        $query=$this->getEntityManager()
             ->createQuery("SELECT u.username
              FROM UserBundle:User u
              WHERE u.id  = $email");
         return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

with the controller function

```
public function findByEmailJsonAction($email)
{
    $users=$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
                ->getRepository('UserBundle:User')
                ->findEmailDQL($email);
    $serializer =  new Serializer([new ObjectNormalizer()]);
    $formatted =$serializer->normalize($users);
    return new JsonResponse($formatted);
}
```

I keep getting this error when I try looking for the user with id 127:

An exception occurred while executing `'SELECT u0_.username AS username_0 FROM user u0_ WHERE u0_.id = 127':`

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Champ 'u0_.username' inconnu dans field list
```

Comment: Your database is out of sync with the entity definition. Depending on your symfony version and whether you're using doctrine migrations will change what exactly you need to do, but for example with Symfony 4 and migraitions you'll need to run `bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff` followed by `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: It sems like you dont have any username column in your db, more like an accessor in your entity User. And prefer dont use raw dql query if you dont need to : $this->createQueryBuilder('users')->where('email = :userEmail')->setParameter('email', $email)->getQuery();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:-)

Try this !

```
$users = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("UserBundle:User")->findBy(array("email" => $email));
```

Or for just one:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository("UserBundle:User")->findOneBy(array("email" => $email));
```

Good luck ! :-)

Comment: I tried both and I keep getting the same error as before, is there a way to access the FOSUser Entity code because I think it has something with the column names

Comment: Please ensure that you updated your sql database: php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force

Answer (score 0):

Symfony `EntityRepository` create `queryBuilder`:

```
class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findEmailDQL($email)
    {
        return $this->createQueryBuilder('u')
            ->select('u.username')
            ->where('u.your_stuff_field = :stuff')
            ->setParameter('stuff' => $email)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult();
    }
}
```